# Streaming video to a browser in a "timeline" as to provide a television like consistant broadcast

Tags: javascript, flash, video, streaming

I know there are several video streaming solutions out there, however I am looking for a solution that might allow me to arrange video content in some sort of "timeline" or allocate video files to particular time slots similar to how television works.

The user would be subjected to the video content that was edited and prepared "ahead of time" for whichever specific time slot that video was prepared and "dropped in" for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wowza with [StreamPublisher](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145) module. You will then have a schedule (you can generate it as you please) that will control the playback. For a simple example check out [streamNerd](http://blog.ianbeyer.com/2011/01/17/wowza-stream-class/) and its [simple playlist generator](http://blog.ianbeyer.com/2011/07/18/wowza-stream-class-playlist-generator/).